# Parse 'a' tags based on attribute using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using this bit of html:

```
    <td align="left">
     <a class="playerLink" href="http://bbroto.baseball.cbssports.com/players/playerpage/2000032">
      Russell, Addison
     </a>
     SS OAK  - Won at $0
     <br>
      <a class="playerLink" href="http://bbroto.baseball.cbssports.com/players/playerpage/556425">
       Vargas, Jason
      </a>
      SP LAA
      <span title="Angels interested in bringing back Jason Vargas">
       <a class="playerLink" href="http://bbroto.baseball.cbssports.com/players/playerpage/556425" subtab="Update">
        <img border="0" height="10" src="http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/news-note-recent.gif" width="10"/>
       </a>
      </span>
      - Dropped
     </br>
    </td>
```

I want to only show the  blocks if they do not have subtab = "Update".  But I haven't been able to figure out how to refer to the subtab in a Python loop using BeautifulSoup.  Here's what I attempted:

```
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        pl = soup.findAll('a',{'class': 'playerLink'})
        for a in pl:
            if a.subtab == "Update":
                print "UPDATE"
            else:
                print "Player Name: " + a.text
```

I also tried referring to the subtype in the findAll part:

```
        pl = soup.findAll('a',{'class': 'playerLink'}, {'subtype':0})
```

Neither of these ways works.  My problem is, the class is 'playerLink' in all cases, so that subtype is the only way I can distinguish it.  I'm very new to BS so I'm not too good at handling tags and attributes.  In the second example, maybe it would work if I only wanted subtype=Update, but I want every a tag where the subtype does not exist.

Comment: `'subtab' not in a.attrs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.attrs` returns `<a>`'s attributes as a dictionary. You could check whether `<a>` tag has no `subtab` attribute using `'subtab' not in a.attrs`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer # pip install beautifulsoup4

player_links = SoupStrainer('a', 'playerLink')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parse_only=player_links)
names = [a.get_text().strip()
         for a in soup.find_all(player_links) if 'subtab' not in a.attrs]
print(names)
# -> ['Russell, Addison', 'Vargas, Jason']
```

I can't find where it is mentioned in [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-value-true) but it seems that specifying `subtab=False` also works to exclude any tag that has `subtab` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer # pip install beautifulsoup4

player_links = SoupStrainer('a', 'playerLink', subtab=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parse_only=player_links)
names = [a.get_text().strip()
         for a in soup.find_all(player_links)]
print(names)
```

If found tags (`player_links`) are not nested then you could omit `.find_all(player_links)` call:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer # pip install beautifulsoup4

player_links = SoupStrainer('a', 'playerLink', subtab=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parse_only=player_links)
names = [a.get_text().strip() for a in soup]
print(names)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getattr()` function to check if an element has an attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')

for a in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'playerLink'}):
    #if getattr(a, 'subtab'): continue
    if a.get('subtab'): continue
    print(a.get_text("", strip=True))
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py htmlfile
```

It yields:

```
Russell, Addison
Vargas, Jason
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  It returns false in every case.  if I insert print getattr(a, 'subtab') it returns "None" in every case.  Maybe because Python 2.7 doesn't have the getattr function?

Comment: @MichaelT: It's because `getattr()` returns a `bool`. You need to compare it to decide if printing. I didn't code it like that. If you modify some code, try to know what you are doing and why.

Comment: Fair enough.  My bad.  I'm not good with Python and I thought a boolean would print true or false or 0 or 1 if I use the print command. But when I add this -- if getattr(a, 'subtab'):  --it is still false in every case.

Comment: @MichaelT: Yes. I was thinking after your previous comment because I had tested it before posting. Perhaps you forgot the `continue` or something like that, while trying to adapt it to your original source code. Simply get the idea that you can check attributes like this, with `a.attrs` as you've discovered, or the qmorgan's solution. There are many ways and most of them work.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, I don't think your code is working.  If you remove the if line it works the same, because the a tag with the subtab attribute has no text, so you are still printing its text, its just blank.  So if instead of continue you say print "subtab" it will not print "subtab".

Comment: @MichaelT: You are right. Sorry. The `markdown` omits last blank lines and confused me in the output. I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but not particularly elegant solution is simply to search for the string 'subtab' in each element:

```
for a in pl:
    if 'subtab' in a.prettify():
        print "UPDATE"
    else:
        print "Player Name: " + a.text
```

Comment: you don't need to convert `a` tag to string to find out whether it has `subtab` attribute. You could use [`'subtab' not in a.attrs`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20433757/4279) instead.

Comment: Good to know - thanks! Your solution is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Messing around with the attrs function I found out this works:

```
if str(a.attrs).find('subtab') > 0
```

It probably isn't the cleanest way to do it, but it works.

Comment: don't use string operations to find out whether a dictionary has a key. Python has builtin syntax for that: `if key in some_dict`. See [my answer for the concrete example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20433757/4279)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"playerLink"})
for container in containers:
      url = ("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(container.get("href"), container.a))
```